# Object doesn't support property or method in IE 11 after upgrading to Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, polyfills

I recently upgrading my application from Angular 4 to Angular 5. The application is running fine in chrome, but when I try to run the application in IE 11 then it gives me the following error and the page does not load.

[image]

The following is the code that I have in polyfills.ts:

```js
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

I followed a lot of links online and they mention about uncommenting the code in polyfills.ts. I did follow that but I was still not able to resolve the issue.

This is how my package.json looks:

```json
{
  "name": "angular4-cliv122",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.6.0",
    "atob": "^2.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "primeng": "^4.2.1",
    "primeui": "^4.1.15",
    "quill": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Could you let me know how I could resolve this issue.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using zone.js 0.8.26 with Angular 5.2.10

Comment: If you got through this problem.  I would love to hear about it.

Comment: @Winnemucca removing the following import from polyfills.ts worked for me. import 'core-js/es7'; I removed this import. Let me know if it does not work.